# e1000 and e1000e network drivers

Tags: linux, networking, drivers

I am using SUSE Linux 11, in Zenworks distro and i can see. kernel version is: 3.0.13-0.27-default.

I can see that when the distro is loaded, the e1000 driver is loaded and not e1000e although e1000e is also present. I have some questions:

1) Why the e1000e driver is not loaded automatically like e1000 ? Does the driver load, based on the compatibility with a particular version of kernel? If yes, how to determine the compatibility (any command)?

2) What is the basic difference between e1000 and e1000e?

3) When is e1000 required to use and e1000e?

**modinfo of e1000**

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.0.13-0.27-default/initrd/e1000.ko
version:        7.3.21-k8-NAPI
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
srcversion:     9156F163ACCABEA3C50ACF0
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002E6Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010B5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001099sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000108Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000107Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000107Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000107Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001079sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001078sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001077sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001076sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001075sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001028sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001027sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001026sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000101Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000101Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000101Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001019sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001018sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001017sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001016sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001015sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001014sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001013sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001012sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001011sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001010sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000100Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000100Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000100Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000100Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001009sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001008sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001004sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001001sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001000sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
supported:      yes
vermagic:       3.0.13-0.27-default SMP mod_unload modversions 586TSC 
parm:           TxDescriptors:Number of transmit descriptors (array of int)
parm:           RxDescriptors:Number of receive descriptors (array of int)
parm:           Speed:Speed setting (array of int)
parm:           Duplex:Duplex setting (array of int)
parm:           AutoNeg:Advertised auto-negotiation setting (array of int)
parm:           FlowControl:Flow Control setting (array of int)
parm:           XsumRX:Disable or enable Receive Checksum offload (array of int)
parm:           TxIntDelay:Transmit Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           TxAbsIntDelay:Transmit Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           RxIntDelay:Receive Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           RxAbsIntDelay:Receive Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           InterruptThrottleRate:Interrupt Throttling Rate (array of int)
parm:           SmartPowerDownEnable:Enable PHY smart power down (array of int)
parm:           copybreak:Maximum size of packet that is copied to a new buffer on receive (uint)
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)
parm:           entropy:Allow e1000 to populate the /dev/random entropy pool (int)
```

**modinfo of e1000e**

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.0.13-0.27-default/initrd/e1000e.ko
version:        1.10.6-NAPI
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
srcversion:     D1F1E8DCB1431A5ED03735A
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001503sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001502sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010EFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010EBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010EAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001525sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010CEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010CDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010CCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010CBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010E5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000294Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001501sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001049sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001098sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001096sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000150Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010D3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000109Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000108Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000108Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000107Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000107Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000107Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010B9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010D5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010D9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001060sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010A5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010A4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000105Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000105Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
supported:      external
vermagic:       3.0.13-0.27-default SMP mod_unload modversions 586TSC 
parm:           copybreak:Maximum size of packet that is copied to a new buffer on receive (uint)
parm:           TxIntDelay:Transmit Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           TxAbsIntDelay:Transmit Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           RxIntDelay:Receive Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           RxAbsIntDelay:Receive Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           InterruptThrottleRate:Interrupt Throttling Rate (array of int)
parm:           IntMode:Interrupt Mode (array of int)
parm:           SmartPowerDownEnable:Enable PHY smart power down (array of int)
parm:           KumeranLockLoss:Enable Kumeran lock loss workaround (array of int)
parm:           CrcStripping:Enable CRC Stripping, disable if your BMC needs the CRC (array of int)
parm:           EEE:Enable/disable on parts that support the feature (array of int)
parm:           Node:[ROUTING] Node to allocate memory on, default -1 (array of int)
```

Answer (score 2):

They support different devices based on the same chip. All those PCI IDs in your modinfo output are used to select the right one. According to the kernel config help, `e1000e` is for PCI-Express cards so I guess the reason it wasn't loaded automatically is that you don't have one of those.

Comment: kernel loads the modules as per the hardware that is attached, so as you pointed out that might be a reason. In betwn. you said: `e1000e is for PCI-Express cards` is this documented somewhere? If yes, can you kindly share the link? It's our customer issue, i will share in turn with them.

Comment: How is this an issue? Is the automatically selected driver not working? The information I got is from reading the help in `make menuconfig`

Comment: That's what he said. It is unable to get the IP address after manually inserting the e1000e, i have asked the same question what you asked me. Let us see what he reverts in bugzilla.

Comment: This link `http://www.stonesoft.com/en/products/fw/Software_Solutions/certified_nics.html` suggests that e1000 supports both PCI and PCI-X.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI-X#Confusion_with_PCI-Express